# Fastest way to sort 2d list by a column in reverse order

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, numpy

Let's say I have a 2d python (rectangular i.e. like matrix) list which I want to sort in descending order based on its 2nd column, and I want the list to change and not interested in a copy. What is the best alternative to this approach (using numpy, ...)

`arr.sort(key= lambda i:i[1],revere=True)`

I've searched a lot but couldn't find an intuitive way that seemed better that the code above.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not test it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give some more informations. A 2d list can be something more than a rectangular 2d numpy array.

In this answer i asume that your data can be represented as a 2d- array.

```
import numpy as np
np_arr=np.array(arr) #create a numpy array from your list
idx=np.argsort(-np_arr[:,1])
np_arr=np_arr[idx,:]
```

Comment: This approach is not correct, because axis is different from column! But thank you for your effort

Comment: Thank you again, now it's right but how is this faster than my solution knowing that it does revere the array, indexes by another array and also creates another array(not in place)?